# Linux terminal emulator with terminal autocomplete?

Tags: linux, terminal, autocomplete

I've moved from OSX back to Linux and am mostly happy. One of the main things I miss is [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/), especially its [terminal based autocompletion](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/autocomplete) feature (tmux integration would also be nice).

I've looked around but couldn't find an equivalent in Linux, any pointers?

(p.s.: I know of shell based autocompletion and I know of editor/IDE autocompletion; I use both, but I also want terminal based autocompletion. That's how I roll.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I've seen to iTerm2 is [Final Term](https://github.com/p-e-w/finalterm). However, it's currently in development with the disclaimer

> Final Term is in heavy development and neither stable nor feature complete!

Some of the features it boasts are

- Semantic text menus
- Start command completion
- GUI terminal controls

A list of available/planned features is available [here](http://finalterm.org/)

Comment: Cheers. They seem to have taken terminal completion a bit too far (semantic completion by the terminal... gah!), but it is in the region of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Bash-completion](https://github.com/GArik/bash-completion) scripts can help with parameters.

You can install the [wash shell](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wash/) a modification of `bash` with the [whispering](http://code.google.com/p/bash-whispering/) mod.

Alternatively `zsh` can be configured with some [autocomplete](https://scottlinux.com/2011/08/19/quick-intro-to-zsh-auto-complete/) (the [ArchLinux liveCD](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) has zsh by default and configured like that)